# Why is my consumer reading all messages from the topic each time, even when auto.offset.reset=largest?

Tags: apache-kafka, offset, kafka-consumer-api

I have produced 5 messages to Kafka on topic1 and consumed them successfully. When I sent 6th message and trying to consume, I am getting all 6 messages again instead of the latest(6th) message.

Please note I am running consumer command line, rather from a database connector(access module). And the connector has the config property auto.offset.reset set to "largest".(please see all the config properties from log below)

Also please see the OffsetChecker output below:

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker \
    --group testjob --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic topic1

[2017-07-06 21:57:46,707] WARN WARNING: ConsumerOffsetChecker is deprecated and will be dropped in releases following 0.9.0. Use ConsumerGroupCommand instead. (kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker$)
Exiting due to: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /consumers/testjob/offsets/topic1/0.
```

Could anyone please let me know where the problem is?

Here is the log that shows config properties:

```
***Global config Properties***
*             client.id = rdkafka
*             message.max.bytes = 1200
*             receive.message.max.bytes = 100000000
*             metadata.request.timeout.ms = 60000
*             topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms = 600000
*             topic.metadata.refresh.fast.cnt = 10
*             topic.metadata.refresh.fast.interval.ms = 250
*             topic.metadata.refresh.sparse = false
*             socket.timeout.ms = 60000
*             socket.send.buffer.bytes = 0
*             socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 0
*             socket.keepalive.enable = false
*             socket.max.fails = 3
*             broker.address.ttl = 300000
*             broker.address.family = any
*             statistics.interval.ms = 0
*             log_cb = 0x7fecb80c6dd0
*             log_level = 6
*             socket_cb = 0x7fecb80cd2f0
*             open_cb = 0x7fecb80ddd30
*             opaque = 0x2641280
*             internal.termination.signal = 0
*             queued.min.messages = 100000
*             queued.max.messages.kbytes = 1000000
*             fetch.wait.max.ms = 100
*             fetch.message.max.bytes = 1049776
*             fetch.min.bytes = 1
*             fetch.error.backoff.ms = 500
*             group.id = testjob
*             queue.buffering.max.messages = 100000
*             queue.buffering.max.ms = 1000
*             message.send.max.retries = 2
*             retry.backoff.ms = 100
*             compression.codec = none
*             batch.num.messages = 1000
*             delivery.report.only.error = false
*             request.required.acks = 1
*             enforce.isr.cnt = 0
*             request.timeout.ms = 5000
*             message.timeout.ms = 300000
*             produce.offset.report = false
*             auto.commit.enable = true
*             auto.commit.interval.ms = 60000
*             auto.offset.reset = largest    <<<<--------
*             offset.store.path = .
*             offset.store.sync.interval.ms = 0
*             offset.store.method = file
*             consume.callback.max.messages = 0
```

Comment: How did you run the consumer? A complete command line might help diagnose what' going wrong.

Comment: Without knowing your consumer one can only guess. Maybe your consumer run less than 60s (auto.commit.interval) and was killed instead of shutdown gracefully. Regarding the missing nodes on zookeeper: It could be that you are running a "new consumer" which doesn't submits the offsets to ZK. Or you don't write to the root path of ZK (which I would recommend). Check you broker config (zookeeper.connect). This might look like: 'localhost:2181/kafka' - in this case you must add the path to your ZK connection string when running the offset checker.

Answer (score 0):

Add this properties 
AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG="earliest" it will work